# How to reference external .jar files in TextMate

Tags: java, macos, textmate

I'm working on a java project that requires constantly running the code, to see if it builds properly.
So I'm trying to reference external jar files, without having to launch the project from the command line (I'm running in TextMate).
Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "constantly running"? Check whether the application works before checking in? If you don't want to use the command line, you could build a command which does it for you and you just have to type the keybinding.

Comment: Any advice on what issue? What problem have you come up to while referencing external jar files?

Comment: Why don't you use a Java IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans? As I get it you want to see if your code compiles fine while you edit it. That is exactly what an IDE does for you (among many, many other useful things).